# How to enter two phone numbers as recipients in Messages

Tags: ios, messages

I don't see a comma (,) on my iPhone when I'm in message mode.

So, how do I enter two numbers? The comma is needed to separate the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

After each recipient, press **+** to add another one.

> Tap into the “To” field and enter the first recipient, then tap the (+) plus button and add other recipients

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/20/send-mass-text-message-iphone/)

If you are manually typing numbers in, you can press <kbd>return</kbd> after each phone number to add another one.